# How to log all elements of a list in Ocaml before returning the list?

Tags: list, ocaml

I would like to log (print for now) all the elements in results before reducing it for return. Is there a way to achieve that?

```
let calculate ~size_of_experiment:s ~number_of_buckets:n =
  let results = run_experiments s n in
  List.iter (fun x -> print_endline x) results;
  List.fold_left (fun x y -> x + (snd y)) 0 results
```

The code above does not compile:

```
Error: This expression has type (int * int) list
       but an expression was expected of type string list
       Type int * int is not compatible with type string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only problem seems to be that elements of the list are of type `(int * int)` and you are treating them as strings.

```
let string_of_int_pair (a, b) = Printf.sprintf "(%d, %d)" a b

let calculate ~size_of_experiment:s ~number_of_buckets:n =
  let results = run_experiments s n in
  List.iter (fun x -> print_endline (string_of_int_pair x)) results;
  List.fold_left (fun x y -> x + (snd y)) 0 results
```

The more general problem is that it would be really nice to have a way to print values of various types without writing the code yourself for each case. For that you can use something like [`deriving`](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/deriving/deriving.0.7.1/).

Comment: Thanks @jeffrey I totally forgot this detail about Ocaml.